# Is there a way to connect Angular to node server?

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, typescript

I'm learning Angular (not angularjs) and what I'm trying to do is have a form and store the data entered to sql database and also query some data from database.

I have looked around and I've not encountered a solution for this. I have seen where people connect using http service to get json data. But how do we do it for sql database.

Does angular even have modules that can connect to a server???
Or should I be looking into noSQL database instead of SQL database.

Please help...

Comment: you could make a rest api with node and have angular access your data with http calls. just have node serve your index.html and all the static files associated with it to run your angular application.

Comment: ah, you would never do this. you would always have a restful service behind it, to store the data

there is this, that kinda does something for you. https://pouchdb.com/

Comment: I don't understand the question. So you are making an http request to your node server but you don't know how to make sql queries within node? or are you trying to access your sql db directly from angular?

Comment: I do not get how all of these come together. Can somebody show me an small example.